Using multiple sources in Zemax mixed mode
In Ansys Zemax OpticStudio [I'm using 2023 R1.00 Pro (11)] sequential mode, the Multi-Configuration Editor can be used to make multiple paths for rays to trace through after the rays depart from a single source.  This enables the use of beam splitters with light going in two alternative directions after the beam splitter.  Instead, I would like to have two different sources that pass through a beam combiner.  I have read that this is impossible in sequential mode.
Conversely in non-sequential mode, it is common to use multiple sources of light.  Is it possible to use mixed mode to place a source of light in a non-sequential group right after the object so that the rays emitted through its exit portal continue on and pass through the rest of the sequentially traced optical system?  If so, is this the best way to trace multiple sources through an optical system?  If this does not work in mixed mode, do I have to use non-sequential mode for the entire system if I'm going to use multiple sources?
I made an example, and the files are located here:
Zemax files
In this example, I have placed a non-sequential group right after the object.  That group contains a source point and a detector rectangle. I have verified that the detector observes the correct cone of light emitted by the source point.  There is a lens located 100 mm beyond the object and non-sequential group.  The 3D Viewer looks like the rays from the non-sequential group are not continuing on to the rest of optical system for sequential tracing.

Mixed mode has lots of limitations, and without looking at your files, I'm guessing it won't work. But mixed mode is VERY sensitive to getting the exit ports right. I'd recommend you get on a Zemax forum and ask.
I prefer to build two systems: sequential to do optimization, wavefronts, etc. and non-sequential to model scatter, multiple sources, etc. More work but in the end you can get the information you are looking for.      You might be able to use sequential alone: use the Multi-config editor to zoom wavelength, NA, etc, and use 'ignore' to turn surfaces on and off.

I tried to get an account on https://community.zemax.com/, and it was not approved, so I can't post my question there.  My company has a network license of Zemax, and maybe that confused them when they tried to confirm my license status.  Do you have any recommendations for other Zemax forums?

Yes, that might well have confused them.  Welcome to the world of customer service for Ansys and Zemax. You should contact Ansys/Zemax, whomever is selling you the license, and tell them you can't get an account. You might be getting the license through a reseller, you may have to ask them for help or email to:  support  at  zemax.com.      Don't give up - eventually you should be able to get help on this.
